# Should I use totalSupply() or a custom counter for ERC-721 token id?

Tags: solidity, erc-721, openzeppelin, openzeppelin-contracts

I'm following OpenZeppelin [ERC721 guide](https://docs.openzeppelin.com/contracts/4.x/erc721). They use a counter (`Counters.Counter`) for the tokenId. My contract inherits from `ERC721Enumerable` so I have `totalSupply()` out of the box.

I was wondering if I could use `totalSupply()` instead of `counter.current()` when I mint a token and if that would be a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

In fact, `totalSupply()` is just the convention function name in ERC 721 to a method that returns the `totalSupply`. You can override it to return the `counter.current()` or use a different approach/value.

Check this example in OpenZeppelin repo: https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/token/ERC721/extensions/ERC721Enumerable.sol#L45

Comment: I'm using OpenZeppelin ERC721Enumerable contract so I have `totalSupply()` out of the box. So my question is if should I add a counter or just use `totalSupply()` as my counter when I mint a token.